# How do i get result which is bigger than an avg ( avg that i don't have )?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am very new to PostgreSQL and to this website. I need your help with this, please.

I need to get all months with more than average rain amount.

I tried this but its not working, may anyone explain?

```
Select month, rain from weather 
where rain > avg(rain)
group by month , rain;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: avg is an agregate function, so you can used it like  that, you may wanna consult documentation on agregate functions usage in sql

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT month FROM (SELECT month, avg(rain) avg_rain FROM weather GROUP BY month) a
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT avg(rain) rain FROM weather) b
WHERE avg_rain > rain
```

Comment: Not working :( i did this at the beginning , it says aggregate functions are not allowed in where

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH rain_avg_by_month AS (
  SELECT month, AVG(rain) AS rain_avg
  FROM weather
  GROUP BY month
), total_rain_avg AS (
  SELECT AVG(rain_avg)
  FROM rain_avg_by_month
)
SELECT month
FROM rain_avg_by_month, total_rain_avg
WHERE rain_avg_by_month.rain_avg > total_rain_avg.avg
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    select
            month,
            rain,
            avg(rain) over() avg_rain
        from weather
    ) t
    where rain > avg_rain;
```

Here we assume there is one record per month. First query (the nested one) gives us all months and corresponding rain values along with average rain value (we use window function `avg` over all records in set). Then the outer query gives us what we need: months where rain value is greater than average rain value.

Comment: this answer assumes one row per month.  I was thinking the OP's data might have been daily observations that have to get agged to month.  But the question is not clear.

Comment: Ok! I've added explanation.